# how to know the fundamental frequency is right detected by fft/lomb-scargle?

Tags: signals, fft

I am using two methods,fft and lomb-scargle, to find periods for a timing sequence points.
However the fundamental frequency changes much even for the same dataset.
I can get the right result only when I fine tune the sampling rate.<>br/

How to choose the parameters of the two methods to get a consistent fundamental frequency. 
How to know the result is reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent "Understanding the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram - 
Jacob T. VanderPlas" that you can find on [This link to arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09824.pdf) is a very good reference on how to chose the right set of parameters and how to test if your results are reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental pitch frequency can be very different from FFT magnitude peak.  Pitch is a psycho-acoustic phenomena, and thus usually requires a different pitch detection/estimation method than just peak frequency estimation (Instead, try YAAPT, RAPT, cepstral/cepstrum, HPS, correlation lag estimators, & etc.)