# detecting fundamental frequency of human voice in iOS

Tags: ios, fft, frequency

I make a wide search about this , I found many useful code examples but they did not gave me the exact result

I need to detect fundamental frequency (F0) of human voice while someone fonating `a:` vowel.

then I look up these code examples;

https://github.com/krafter/DetectingAudioFrequency from krafter 
https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio

but none of them gave me the fundamental frequency , all of them gives the strongest frequency so this usually equals to F2 or F3 harmonics. 
I need help to calculate the fundamental frequency with this code examples by modifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify an FFT peak detector for correct voice pitch estimation.  It's the wrong algorithm.  Instead, try autocorrelation, or one of the answers to this question: [how to know the fundamental frequency is right detected by fft/lomb-scargle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782489/how-to-know-the-fundamental-frequency-is-right-detected-by-fft-lomb-scargle/20806866#20806866)

Comment: Is there any code sapmle to demonstrate this algoritms ?